# How can I find if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n! \over 10^n} $ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n! \over  10^n} $$

I wasn't sure on which method to use, I think the ratio test might work, but I'm stuck. Here's what I have so far:

$a_n$= $n! \over 10^n$ &  $a_{n+1}={(n+1)! \over 10^{n+1}} $ = $(n+1)! \over (10^n)(10^1)$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {(n+1)! \over (10^n)(10^1)} \cdots {10^n \over n!}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {(n+1)! \over (n!)(10^1)}$$

$$ {1 \over 10} \lim_{n\to\infty}  {(n+1)! \over n!}$$

I don't even know if what I've done is correct, but even if it is I could use some help with simplification

Comment: You are using the ratio test so carry on.

Comment: Simplify one more step! What's $(n+1)! / n!$?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know those were equivalent. Then the limit is infinity and thus divergent

Comment: See the cases of the ratio test.

Comment: You shouldn't **know** that they are equivalent. Rather, you should just go back to the definition of $n!$. It is the product of the first $n$ positive integers. So it is clear what $(n+1)! \div n!$ would be.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if there was some trick to get rid of the '!' that I was supposed to use

Comment: This thing is BEGGING for a ratio test.

Comment: Please use more informative titles. The previous title you had, was on par with "Help!".

Comment: @Aryabhata That's how I draw you in, just kidding, but seriously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=(n+1)$$

according to your solution the series becomes diverge

Answer (score 2):

Although the ratio test works here, it is usually better to understand the actual structure of the series. In this case $n!$ grows faster than $10^n$ in the following way. $\frac{n!}{10^n} > \frac{10!10^{n-10}}{10^n} = \frac{10!}{10^{10}}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>10}$, and so the series consists of infinitely many terms that are more than $\frac{10!}{10^{10}}$.

Comment: Spot on.  This is useful for many closer questions.  Stirling's approximation says $n! \approx \left(\frac ne \right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$, so $n!$ eventually grows faster than $k^n$ for any fixed $k$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks! Yup Stirling's approximation is great. I'd be curious if you know any elegant method that can be used to derive to arbitrary order the asymptotic expansion using completely elementary methods, though.

Comment: Sorry, can't help.  I have read proofs of the approximation, but usually they don't derive more terms.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)  has more terms, but I don't see the general term.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{10^n} $$
Note that $n! \gt 10^n$ when $n \geq 25$. So as $n\to\infty$, it's clear that the numerator grows faster than the denominator. So now we have
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{10^n} =\infty $$
Therefore by the limit test
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{10^n} =\ \mbox{diverges}$$

Comment: You might want to considering adding a brief proof/rationale for why that's true.

Comment: @AlfredYerger, Agreed. Please see my edit.